# ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I've tried lots of suggestions on the Internet in order to run `executeScalar`, but I get the error `ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized`.  My `INSERT` query is working fine, the problem is with `executeScalar`.

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Products (Product_Name,Product_BarCode,Product_CP,Product_SP,
                           Product_Countainer,Product_Pcs,Product_MFGDate,
                           Product_ExpiryDate,Product_Grade)
     Values ('" + Name.Text + "','" + BarCode.Text + "','" + CostP.Value + "','" + 
             SellingP.Value + "','" + Countainer.Value + "','" + Pcs.Value + "','" + 
             MfgDate.Value + "','" + ExpDate.Value + "','" + Grade.SelectedItem + "')", 
     conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

```
conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Product_CP) FROM Products AS Amount");
Amount = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
MessageBox.Show(Amount.ToString());
conn.Close();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: No problem with that it is just a small application for home use.
With not internet connection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(...);
```

As the error clearly states, this command doesn't have a connection.

Comment: +1 I wrongly assumed assigning a transaction to a command would be sufficient, since the transaction has a connection.  But no, I needed to set the command's connection to the connection property of the command's transaction.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall , I can understand this behavior when outside a `using`, but when inside a `using` block it seems obvious what connection should be used.  But I guess I can make it explicit.

Comment: I didn't really understand what to do. Can you please elaborate what to do with `cmd = new SqlCommand(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

In Case you are using DBCommand instead of SQLCommand, this won't be able to solve the problem as DBCommand is an Abstract class and can not be instantiated..

The solution that worked for me was : i was using command.executeScalar() where i had to use: DbCommand.executeScalar (command) // works wonders!

Answer (score 0):

This `cmd.Connection = conn;`

should be after declaration

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Product_CP) FROM Products AS Amount");
cmd.Connection = conn;
```